# Вывести просты числа (2,3,5,7)

Tags: javascript

Я нашел код решения данной задачи, но не могу разобраться с логикой решения.

```
for (var i=2; i<=10; i++){
    for(var j=2; j<=i; j++){
        if (i%j == 0) break;
    }
    if(j==i) console.log(i);
}
```

Выводит (2,3,5,7). Но 4%4==0//true, дальше идет до if(j==i) console.log(i); и тут 4==4//true, но он его не выводит. Я уже больше часа сижу и не могу понять, где я в логике ошибся.

```
for (var i=2; i<=10; i++){
    console.log(i+' i');
    for(var j=2; j<=i; j++){
        console.log(j+' j');
        if (i%j == 0) break;
    }
    if(j==i) console.log(i);
}
```

Алилуя

```
2 i 
2 j 
2 
3 i 
2 j 
3 j 
3 
4 i 
2 j 
5 i 
2 j 
3 j 
4 j 
5 j 
5 
6 i 
2 j 
7 i 
2 j 
3 j 
4 j 
5 j 
6 j 
7 j 
7 
8 i 
2 j 
9 i 
2 j 
3 j 
10 i 
2 j
```

Comment: дальше же он идет на if(j==i) console.log(i); и соответственно должен выводить 4, ведь break прерывает только 1 цикл

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Загвоздка тут вот в чем - ваш внутренний цикл увеличивает j  и провер\яет условие, делится ли i  на j без остатка. Если да, то число не является простым, а потому внутренний цикл прерывается. В случае с 4 он прерывается на j равном 2 (4 на 2 делится безз остатка). Следовательно во внешнем цикле происходит сравнение четырех и двух. Это услови е не выполняется, соответственно, 4, не будучи простым числом, на консоль не выводится

Comment: все равно не понимаю.

2<=10 // true
2<=2 //true
 2%2 == 0 // true - break
2==2 // выводит 2 

3<=10 // true
3<=3 //true
 3%3 == 0 // true - break
3==3 // выводит 3 

4<=10 // true
4<=4 //true
 4%4 == 0 // true - break
4==4 // выводит 4

Comment: что конкретно непонятно? Пройдитесь отладчиком, сразу все встанет на свои места

Comment: после break j увеличивается на 1?

Comment: Нет не увеличивается. Он увеличивается только  циклом. Еще раз говорю - пройдитесь отладчиком и посмотрите

Comment: а как отладчиком пройтись?

Comment: читайте в документации к вашей IDE

Comment: Я просто через Sublime это делаю,  сейчас скачаю webstorm посмотрю как  отладчиком вообще пользоваться. Спасибо

Comment: js отладчик встроен почти в любой браузер - f12 нажимайте. есть еще слово debugger;  - если его написать, то случится break point

Comment: Дружище, спасибо тебе, я ломал над этим голову 3 с половиной часа, а оказалось все настолько просто что аж смешно слегка:D
Но самое главное что я нашел решение по крупицам и понял тему!!!
Еще раз огромное спасибо. До меня тупо не доходила логика решения этой задачи:D